# RStudio not showing code in Rmd file, while Notepad does

Tags: r, rstudio, notepad

I'm currently running into an issue of a .Rmd file opening in RStudio without actually populating the Source pane with the code. The file was written in RStudio, and the code shows up when I open the file in Notepad (and copies with the right formatting), but there's nothing showing up inside of RStudio.

Has anyone run into this issue before or have a good fix?

[image: The blank workspace]

Comment: So *entire* file is blank in RStudio including markdown text (i.e., non-code chunks)? Please post screenshot of this odd, yet interesting issue. Try stopping all rstudio processes and even restart machine. Might be crash out of previous session.

Comment: This is _right_ after I open RStudio, so it shouldn't relate to any issues with a previous session. The entire file pulls up as blank, as if nothing has been written and you are on the first line of code. I'm adding a screenshot above.

Comment: I have had hiccups with RStudio with previous sessions still lingering in background. Really try restarting machine or restarting processes and see if .Rmd still renders blank.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same challenge too. I had to install Rstudio directly from CRAN and it works now, this issue probably happens with R studio installed via Anaconda.